# nginx url rewrite regex with special characters

Tags: nginx, rewrite, regex

How to write a regex that matches a path node with reserved characters like '+','-' ? for example:

`https://e.example.com/foo+/bar/file/test.txt` need to be re-written as `https://e.example.com/bar/file/test.txt`

I tried `rewrite ^/foo+(/.*)$ break;` but it couldn't match the string.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `nginx` `rewrite` directive uses the normalized URI for matching. Normalized URI does not include query arguments or indexed search arguments.

You might be able to use a `map` here:

```
map $request_uri $filefromarg {
    ^[^+]*\+(.*)$ $1;
    default $request_uri;
}
```

And in the `server` block you would have:

```
try_files $filefromarg $uri =404;
```

The `map` takes `$request_uri`, which contains the full path to resource and query arguments. The first line regular expression captures everything after `+` sign and sets it to `$filefromarg` variable.

Then, in the `try_files` section that is used as the path to check for resource to serve.